# How does xarray's interp nearest method choose the nearest center?

Tags: python, interpolation, python-xarray

I have a 2-dimensional xarray dataset that I want to interpolate on the lon and lot coordinates such that I have a higher resolution, but the values correspond exactly with the original values at each coordinate.
I thought the excellent [`xr.interp`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.interp.html) function would be able to do this, but following [the example](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html) I see some discrepancy between the original and interpolated values. I am increasing the longitude and latitude resolution by 4, and thus would except all `air` values that occur once in the original dataset, to occur 16 times in the interpolated dataset, but this is not the case.

Does anyone know what the cause is that the original and interpolated dataset do not align and how I could solve it?

```
ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature").isel(time=0)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4))
ds_sel=ds.sel(lon=slice(250,260),lat=slice(40,30))
ds.air.plot(ax=axes[0],xlim=(250,260),ylim=(30,40))

axes[0].set_title("Raw data")

# Interpolated data
new_lon = np.linspace(ds.lon[0], ds.lon[-1], ds.dims["lon"] * 4)
new_lat = np.linspace(ds.lat[0], ds.lat[-1], ds.dims["lat"] * 4)

dsi = ds.interp(lat=new_lat, lon=new_lon,method="nearest")
dsi_sel=dsi.sel(lon=slice(250,260),lat=slice(40,30))
dsi.air.plot(ax=axes[1],xlim=(250,260),ylim=(30,40))


axes[1].set_title("Interpolated data")
```

[image: Link]

Showing the unique values with

```
unique, counts = np.unique(ds_sel.air.values, return_counts=True)
print("original values",dict(zip(unique, counts)))
unique, counts = np.unique(dsi_sel.air.values, return_counts=True)
print("interpolated values",dict(zip(unique, counts)))
```

I get

```
original values {262.1: 1, 263.1: 1, 263.9: 1, 264.4: 1, 265.19998: 1, 266.6: 1, 266.79: 1, 266.9: 2, 268.29: 1, 269.79: 1, 270.4: 1, 273.0: 1, 273.6: 1, 275.19998: 1, 276.29: 1, 278.0: 1, 278.5: 1, 278.6: 1, 281.5: 1, 282.1: 1, 282.29: 1, 284.6: 1, 286.79: 1, 288.0: 1}
```

```
interpolated values {262.1: 4, 263.1: 8, 263.9: 8, 264.4: 8, 265.19998: 4, 266.6: 16, 266.79: 16, 266.9: 24, 268.29: 8, 269.79: 20, 270.4: 10, 273.0: 20, 273.6: 16, 275.19998: 8, 276.29: 20, 278.0: 16, 278.5: 10, 278.6: 8, 281.5: 4, 282.1: 16, 282.29: 8, 284.6: 8, 286.79: 8, 288.0: 4}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're conceptually running up against a fencepost error (see the section on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

You should interpret the xarray coordinates as "midpoints", not as the cell boundaries.

Your `new_lon` isn't nicely divided into 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc.:

```py
print(new_lon)
[200.         200.61611374 201.23222749 201.84834123 202.46445498
 203.08056872 203.69668246 204.31279621 204.92890995]
```

And it doesn't include all the original coordinates.

Taking the "off-by-ones" into account:

```py
new_lon = np.linspace(ds.lon[0], ds.lon[-1], (ds.dims["lon"] - 1) * 4 + 1)
new_lat = np.linspace(ds.lat[0], ds.lat[-1], (ds.dims["lat"] - 1) * 4 + 1)
print(new_lon)
[200.    200.625 201.25  201.875 202.5   203.125 203.75  204.375 205.   ]
```

You can then e.g. inspect the part of the first row of the original and the interpolated one:

```py
selection = ds["air"][0, :3]
selection_i = dsi["air"][0, :9]
print(selection["lon"])
print(selection.values)
print(selection_i["lon"])
print(selection_i.values)
```

This looks good to me:

```py
[200.  202.5 205. ]
[241.2 242.5 243.5]
[200.    200.625 201.25  201.875 202.5   203.125 203.75  204.375 205.   ]
[241.2   241.2   241.2   242.5   242.5   242.5   242.5   243.5   243.5]
```

Of course, when doing nearest interpolation, you might end up with ties:
0.5 is equally far removed from 0.0 as it is from 1.0 -- and so you inadverntely have to bias either "up" or "down" to get a single nearest value.

Also note that the `.plot()` command, which draws a Matplotlib QuadMesh has to infer boundaries from midpoints somehow. This can sometimes lead to boundaries being drawn slightly differently from what you might have in mind (especially if the coordinate is unevenly spaced).